# The nav bar moving to the left when switching from home to different page due to img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I'm new to web development, i recently started practicing Reactjs. I wanted to create my own portfolio site as a practice. I made a navbar as a component and similarly a home page. I want a picture of a person below navbar in the home page, if it makes sense. I created a img tag and inserted an image but the navbar tends to move when every I switch through pages.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Project from "./pages/Project";
import Skills from "./pages/Skills";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="main-container">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/project" element={<Project />} />
                <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default App;



import "./Navbar.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
return (
    <nav className="nav">
        <div className="right">
            <ul className="nav-links">
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/" className="a">
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/about" className="a">
                        About
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/project" className="a">
                        Project
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/skills" className="a">
                        Skills
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/contact" className="a">
                        Contact
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
);
};

export default Navbar;


.nav {
display: flex;
height: 60px;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #171923;
align-items: center;
}

ul {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
gap: 4em;
}

ul li a {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-links li:hover a {
color: #4c9e9e;
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-links a.active {
color: #4c9e9e;
}


import React from "react";
import photo1 from "../images/photo1.jpg";

const Home = () => {
return (
    <main>
        <div className="top">
            <img src={photo1} alt="" className="hero-img" />
        </div>
        <div className="mid">
            <div className="title">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, recusandae.
            </div>
            <div className="desc">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corrupti, veniam?
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="end">
            <span>
                <button>connect</button>
            </span>
            <span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact">contact me</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
    </main>
);
};

export default Home;


main {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: calc(100vh - 60px);
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.hero-img {
max-width: 670px;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't reproduce the issue you're describing.   Best advice is to pare back and introduce individual pages/CSS/components one at a time until you observe the issue you're describing.  That'll help you to either create a minimally reproducible example here or identify the source of the issue on your own.